# How to create a table with sum of a datapoints in a given month in R

Tags: r

So I have a dataset with 5000 data points over 3 years, each row is a unique order (in dd/mm/yyy). How can I manipulate this to a return the sum of each data point per month? So I can then plot a graph with x amount of sales in june '14, x amount in july '14 etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use `substring(df$Date, 4)` to substring the date column by removing `dd/`
2. Aggregate with `aggregate(df, by = df$Date, sum)`

Comment: What is the 4 there for in the substring? Also when I do substring it returns the error:
 'Error in aggregate.data.frame(adata1, by = adata1$OrderDate, sum) : 
  'by' must be a list)

adata1 is the DF and OrderDate is the column containing the dates

Comment: 4 means the fourth letter in your Date, which is used to remove `dd/` so that we will only have month info. Try `aggregate(adata1, by = list(adata1$OrderDate), sum)`

Comment: I think this will work, just for some reason it has imported my date as a character, I'll go try and change it into date format and try again

Comment: I think character is fine, otherwise we cannot `substring` it.

Comment: the that returns is: invalid 'type' (character) or argument. Suggesting that it needs to be in date format?

Comment: Which step is it?

Comment: That error appears when I ran:
aggregate(adata1, by = list(adata1$OrderDate), sum)
and when I check typeof for the date it returns as a double

Comment: after you substring it you can convert the date to `factor`, try `adata1$OrderDate <- as.factor(adata1$OrderDate)` before `aggregate`

Comment: It's still returning the same error. R is really not happy with this haha. The class for OrderDate is now factor instead of POSIXct and says it is not subsettable

Comment: use `adata1[, column number of your date]` instead of the `$`

Comment: I made some changes in excel said it would import as a date better (sin I know but times are desperate) and ran the same (but with a 6 instead of 4 at the beginning) so the substring is in the format MM-YY and it all worked fine apart from the aggregate. aggregate(adata1, by = list(adata1$OrderDate), sum) returned the same error as before iwth the invalid type. aggregate(adata1, by = list(adata1[, 3]), sum) gives an error because the arguments must have the same left

Comment: `aggregate(sales ~ format(OrderDate, "%Y-%m"), data = adata1, sum)` Does it work?

Comment: error invalid 'trim' argument returns from that. I've now bound a column on with the date in mm-YY and I'm going to add a column on called sales that just contains value 1 that hopefully that method should work with them 2 columns

Comment: Make sure your sales column is `numeric`. Run `sapply(adata1, class)` and what's the output?

Comment: I added the row in, but it's still returning invalid trim argument

Comment: If you can give me your data and code, that should be much better. Without a reproducible example it's very hard for me to understand your issue.

Comment: How would I be able to do that?

Comment: So I managed to found how to do it, I could subset by date and month and just run it for each date month, this is the code I used:
jan2017<-filter(adata, format(adata$OrderDate, '%m')=="01" & format(adata$OrderDate, "%y")=="17")

Comment: Sounds good! BTW, do you mind to upvote or accept my answer? I need some points to be able to make comments so that I can ask a question on another issue. I will upvote your question as well. Thank you!

Comment: sorry, done it now for you